# Passing random value in tensorflow function as a parameter

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have code in my augmentation tf.data pipeline...

```
    # BLURE
    filter_size = tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0, maxval=5)
    image = tfa.image.mean_filter2d(image, filter_shape=filter_size)
```

But I'm constantly getting error...

```
 TypeError: The `filter_shape` argument must be a tuple of 2 integers. Received: Tensor("filter_shape:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

I tried getting static value from random tensorflow like this...

```
    # BLURE
    filter_size = tf.get_static_value(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0, maxval=5))
    image = tfa.image.mean_filter2d(image, filter_shape=filter_size)
```

But I get error...

```
TypeError: The `filter_shape` argument must be a tuple of 2 integers. Received: None
```

And this errors makes me sad :(

I want to create augmentation pipeline for `tf.data` btw...

Comment: I think you want to add a `2` like so: `tf.random.uniform(shape=[2], minval=0, maxval=5)`

Answer (score 0):

You should specify an output shape. However, when I did that I ran into another error which hints that the shape requested by `mean_filter2d` should *not* be a `Tensor`. Therefore, I decided to simply go with the `random` module to generate a random tuple to modify your image.

```
import random
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

filter_size = tuple(random.randrange(0, 5) for _ in range(2))
image_bllr = tfa.image.mean_filter2d(image, filter_shape=filter_size)
```

Comment: I was thinking about this to do like this but I'm scared to involved GIL into the party, because I'm doing this in the tf.data.Dataset().map and I need GPU parallelization. Is your method safe to use it in dataset map function without activating GIL???

Comment: Your solution does not work in `Dataset().map()` function... ` AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'randrange'`

Comment: Are you sure you used `import random` and not `from random import random`? Data loading typically does not happen on the GPU, but on the CPU in the background while your model optimization uses the GPU. You can easily do this in a parallel fashion as well. Are you certain you *need* to run it on the GPU?

Comment: I got error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: What python version are you using? I confirmed now that this code is running on Python 3.9.7

Comment: I'm running 3.9 but I think you don't know in which content I'm using this code... This is minimal example in which I get this error: https://gist.github.com/urosjarc/1abfc78a3a722781736a7e7c4e982af7

Comment: 1. This is actually a different question. 
2. Again, you are working on CPU (using numpy) and GPU (tensorflow) at the same time. Replace the line with `data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.randint(0, 255, [5, 100, 100, 3]))` and it should run. 
3. Remember: loading data almost always happens on the CPU! Only the actual training uses GPU. Dataloading will transfer it to GPU automatically (the result of the transform will yield a tensor!)